# Three Fiber not showing transparent png texture

Tags: three.js, png, textures, alpha, react-three-fiber

I would like to display a small logo, a transparent png, on the back of each tile in my game. However, the png is not displaying.

Here is the png:

[image]

Here is the code for the texture:

```
import { TextureLoader } from 'three/src/loaders/TextureLoader';

import { useLoader } from '@react-three/fiber'

import * as THREE from 'three'

export default function Tile() {
    ...
    const tileBackTexture = useLoader(THREE.TextureLoader, './presets_library/Tile_Back_Logo.png')
    const tileBackTextureMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ 
        map: tileBackTexture, 
        alphaMap: tileBackTexture,
        transparent: true,
        side: THREE.DoubleSide,
        alphaTest: 0.5,
        depthWrite: false,
        opacity: 0.0,
    });
    ...
    return (
        <mesh geometry={nodes.Tile_Back_Face.geometry} material={tileBackTextureMaterial} />
    )
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

With the model, I made a separate, floating face just for the loaded texture. I have made sure that the png itself had a transparent background. With loading the texture, I made sure transparent was set to true, map was set to the loaded png, that alphaMap was set to the loaded png, but nothing changed.

I've also tried [making the png smaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17422505/plane-material-with-png-alpha-transparency-from-json-export-mesh-is-not-working), [adding an opacity attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17486614/three-js-png-texture-alpha-renders-as-white-instead-as-transparent), but I can't seem to find what might be preventing it from showing up.

If anyone knows what might be going wrong, please let me know.

Thank you.

Update:

Even drawing the image on a canvas and using that image to create the texture and material doesn't show it:

```
    let img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin='Anonymous';
    
    let ctx = canvasRef.current.getContext('2d', { alpha: true, desynchronized: false, colorSpace: 'srgb', willReadFrequently: true})
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "copy";

    img.onload = function () {
        ctx.width = img.width;
        ctx.height = img.height;
        ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
        
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    }

    img.src = './presets_library/Tile_Back_Logo_Small.png';
    
    const texture = new THREE.Texture(canvasRef.current);
    
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ 
        map: texture,
        alphaMap: texture, 
    });
```

The canvasRef is displaying the png, yet for some reason can't be seen on the tiles.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, without *THREE*:

```
const tex = useLoader(TextureLoader, 'tex.jpg')
```

https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/tutorials/loading-textures

Comment: Unfortunately, I still don't see the texture showing up.  I suspected something was wrong with the png, but after having it properly display in Blender as well as in img and canvas elements I am not sure what is going wrong.

Comment: Can you provide codesanbox?

Comment: It has already been solved, but thank you anyways! https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-three-fiber-texture-loader-mgkpgz?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-three-fiber-texture-loader-mgkpgz?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js), and it has been solved. I should have just used the useTexture hook.